# JSON Array Syntax in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON text as response from a web API:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "invoiceId": "26825",
        "additionService": [
            2
        ],
        "invoiceStatusTxt":"OK"
    }
}
```

I'm using `JSONParser` to get a `JSONArray` from the `additionService` key. But, it is showing a JSON error. My code is:

```
JSONObject RES = JSONParser.getJSON(URL_API);
JSONArray ob = RES.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("additionService");
```

The error messages are as follows:

```
W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for additionService
W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:574)
```

i has used json parser before, when i get value from key invoiceId.. it work, i have problem with additionService –

Comment: Please also post the error that you are getting

Comment: i has updated my ans

Comment: Its showing that there is no value for the key 'additionService' in the json object you get from RES.getJSONObject("data"). Can you print whats in 'RES.getJSONObject("data")' and comment that

Comment: For the above code I am getting value for `additionService`
 are you sure the JSON is correct ?

Comment: @SachinGupta I agree, there is no error in presented JSON, are you sure that printing URL_API will generate above Json String?

Comment: When you're first learning JSON you should avoid "long chain polymer" statements like the plague.  Do it one step at a time and dump what you received after each step.

Comment: i has used jsonparser before, when i get value from key invoiceId.. it work, i have problem with additionService

Answer (score 1):

I tried it this way. Seems to be working:

```
String str = "{\"code\":0,\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":{\"invoiceId\":\"26825\",\"additionService\":[2],\"invoiceStatusTxt\":\"OK\"}}";
JSONObject obj=(JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(str);
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) obj.get("data");
JSONArray additionService = (JSONArray) data.get("additionService");
System.out.println(additionService);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown at the `getJSONObject("data")` call, so the data field is empty. You should make an `#isNull()` check on the value returned by `#getJsonObject()`. Then, if it exists, get the array from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data is corrent. I assume that your problem lies somewhere else, either your input String is wrong, or your library.

Little test that works (JDK7):

```
  @Test
  public void testJson() {
    String URL_API = "{\"code\": 0,\"message\": \"Success\",\"data\": {\"invoiceId\": \"26825\",\"additionService\": [2],\"invoiceStatusTxt\":\"OK\"}}";

    JSONObject RES = new JSONObject(URL_API);
    JSONArray ob = RES.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("additionService");
    System.out.print(ob); // prints [2]
  }
```

My pom.xml dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JSONParser parse method

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(URL_API);
JSONObject dataObject= (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
JSONArray additionService = (JSONArray) dataObject.get("additionService");
```

In your case I think there is type cast error.